# Hexadecimal text to string and locate specific information

Tags: mysql, sql, hex

First off, I am working in a `MySQL` database. I have a table where a column's values are stored as very long hexadecimal texts **(to put things in context, it contains information about people's computer specifications - their dxdiag file content)**. I am going to need to search for specific specifications **(e.g., for people who have 2 gigs of ram or more)**.

For instance, the relevant line in that big text might read "Memory: 4096MB Ram" in this example.

Of course, there are a lot of other information such as processor, graphics card etc.

So I guess there are two steps that I need:

1. To correctly locate where the relevant piece is (in this case, "Memory:").
2. to organize it in a way that I can identify the actual ram value as a number and then query for the specific conditions I want.

So I wonder what would be the most efficient way and code to go about this?

P.S. If you're interested, below is a partial example for the data I have. You can convert it to text using this website: http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx

> `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`

Comment: Why store text as hex data. If this helps, try the MySQL `BLOB` type.

Comment: Thanks Cole. It was given to me like this, but I can try and ask the owners. What would be the advantage of storing it as BLOB type?

Comment: Arbitrary lengths (up to a certain limit as posed by the type) and the ability to store data in the database (images and files should be kept out of the db however)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, see my question below, I found the solution to your part of the problem. You can cast the hex to varbinary and then to varchar, without too much difficulty using SQL.  The bigger problem is at the next level, other then first 128 ASCII characters which are pretty much a direct convert for all encoding, there are a bunch of ways to encode to binary or hex, if you don't have or can't use the original conversion tool there are a number of challenges where all the solutions may be unique.

[How to replace non-standard Unicode with Space or Tab using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135902/how-to-replace-non-standard-unicode-with-space-or-tab-using-sql)