# How to replace non-standard Unicode with Space or Tab using SQL

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

I have a SQL2008 R2 database with several fields having the data type [IMAGE] the values in the field are actually BLOBs representing varied formats of mostly text.  The Binary Data is created by HP’s Service Manager where they are used internally to populate tables and arrays in the GUI.  I am using BIRT (4.2) the Eclipse-based reporting tool, to harvest data and create reports.

While it is possible to convert the IMAGE to table arrays, performance issues, preclude that in many cases.  I am trying to create a fully SQL based solution to translate and dissect the IMAGE to readable, usable text.  The Binary characters I care about are mostly in the first 127 Unicode set, and all in the first 255 Unicode.  There is a bunch of garbage outside of this range that is presumably used for formatting in the GUI.

I am looking for a SQL solution that replaces values outside of basic Unicode (127 or 255) with a space or tab.  My attempts to use replace() failed as it only seems to recognize the basic Unicode characters.  My best solution would replace blocks of garbage outside of a given Unicode range with a single tab (and be as simple as existing solutions below).

I have one solution the converts it to a string with some garbage left in it.

```
select
-- Raw is an image, limited options for cast, so cast it as varbinary
-- Default characters converted is 30 so set to (8000) 
-- then cast varbinary to varchar (so a person can read it)
-- substring ignores the first 9 characters after casting
substring (cast (cast (Table.a as varbinary (8000))as varchar(8000)), 9, 7991)as 'SubstringCastCast'

from dbo.Table
```

*I have a screen shot of the data preview, but insufficient reputation to post it, It does not transfer well via copy and paste.*

I have another solution where I find and extract the one piece that I need (i.e. IM0012001234)

```
select 
-- Extract the 12 digit ticket number
  substring (CastCast,
-- Find start of Ticket number
    charindex('IM',CastCast)
    , 12) as 'ETicket'

 --Create data set with string that contains ticket, so I can extract it above
from(
select
-- use cast to get a small data set with the ticket number in it
cast (cast (Table.a as varbinary (200))as varchar(200)) as 'CastCast'

from dbo.Table
)InnerQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a function that strips out anything other than A-Z a-z 0-9... maybe this can help (tweak to suit your needs, you can put in `ELSE ' '` to put in a space where the characters are unrecognised):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripPunctuation]
(
@String VARCHAR(255)
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(255) AS

/*
$   Description: Strips out all non alpha-numeric
$             characters from a string
$
*/

BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @Char CHAR(1)
DECLARE @Wk VARCHAR(255)

-- Only copy 0-9, a-z, A-Z.

SET @Wk = ''
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
BEGIN
   SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@String, @i, 1)
   IF (ASCII(@Char)  > 47) AND (ASCII(@Char)  < 58)
      SET @Wk = @Wk + @Char
   IF (ASCII(@Char)  > 64) AND (ASCII(@Char)  < 91) 
      SET @Wk = @Wk + @Char
   IF (ASCII(@Char)  > 96) AND (ASCII(@Char)  < 123) 
      SET @Wk = @Wk + @Char
   SET @i = @i +1
END

RETURN @Wk

END
```

Comment: Thank you, this is my first attempt at using a function in SQL so going slow as I work on applying & customizing it.

Comment: Thanks again, I have it up and running on my test server and just beginning to play around with customizing it to meet my needs.  It seems to be working just as advertised.